# Xamarin Forms MVVM with an actual model

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm fairly new to Xamarin and stumbled across MVVM and really like it as an architectural pattern. However, I found that most HowTo's and tutorials out there only address the VVM (i.e. View-ViewModel) side of things, probably for simplicity sake!?

I would like to know how the *communication* between a ModelView and its associated models takes place using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` paradigm and other things.

If I understand correctly, I personally would put stuff like data handling, data storage (collections), db connections and stuff like that into a model. At least this is how I would've been doing it in the good old MVC days. Following questions arouse in my mind:

- Where do I create the model(s) and how do I assign them to ViewModels?
- How do I properly *connect* Model and ViewModel such that property updates are propagated and can be handled correctly?
- Would you set the model as a member of the ViewModel?

In my current example, I would like to implement a `SensorModel` which provides several sensory data which layers above can *subscribe* to. I would like to send updates whenever new sensor data is available to the layers above; i.e. a ViewModel, for instance.

I'd basically had something like this in mind:

```
class Sensor
{
    int _id { get; set; }
    string _name { get; set; }
}

class SensorModel
{
    private List<Sensor> _sensors { get; set; }
    public void addSensor(Sensor s) ...
    public void removeSensor(Sensor s) ...
}
```

Does anybody have links to actual/complete MVVM examples, **including** the connection between Model and ViewModel?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*Use Lastest stable Xamarin Forms*

**MODELS**

In the Project, create a *Models* folder

To store data, i usually use SQLite or a temp store:

```
class DataStore
{
    public static List<SensorModel> SensorStore { get; set; }
}
```

Create the *SensorModel* model

```
class SensorModel
{
    internal int Id { get; set; }
    internal string Sensor { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEWMODELS**

In the Project, create a *ViewModels* folder

Create a *SensorVM* viewmodel

```
class SensorVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand StartCommand { get; set; }

    public string SensorName { get; set; }

    public SensorVM()
    {
        DataStore.SensorStore = new List<SensorModel>();
        StartCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(StartSubmit);
    }

    private void StartSubmit(object paramter)
    {
        var sensor = new SensorModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Sensor = SensorName
        };

        AddSensor(sensor);
    }

    public void AddSensor(SensorModel sensor)
    {
        //do something
        DataStore.SensorStore.Add(sensor);
    }
}
```

**VIEWS**

In the Project, create a *Views* folder

Create a *Sensor.xaml* view

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="10" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Entry Text="{Binding SensorName}"  />
        <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Text="Start" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In the code behind:

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Sensor : ContentPage
{
    SensorVM vm;
    public Sensor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm = new SensorVM();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting to see how people interpret the word Model differently. To me, a Model is basically what you described as the `DataStore`. It encapsulates everything that has to do with the data, the actual collection of sensors. What you described as a `SensorModel` is simply a `Sensor` to me, because it doesn't do anything, it's just a basic POCO. The "hack" you did with the static collection is usually packed into a model, imho.

Comment: It's not a hack, it's a convenient way to have it available to other objects throughout the life cycle of the user or app.

Comment: The model is NOT a datastore. The model is a DTO/POCO alright, but it has the power of simplicity. With this you can create persistent data, pass data around, and make meaning of incoming web data. I think you are not used to the concept of SoC, maybe you come from the very classic WinForms/vb.net

Comment: I don't even come from a windows context. To me, what you consider the complete model, i.e. the classes that describe the data you handle, is PART of the model. But what about logic? Let me quote the .NET docs: "..., which usually includes a data model along with business and validation logic.". I want the logic of handling data received via network, for instance, to be separate from the ViewModel, which imho is more drawn to what happens in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how the communication between a ModelView and its
>   associated models takes place using the INotifyPropertyChanged
>   paradigm and other things.

I think the best way to create a communication in MVVM is Messaging Center.
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

It's not coupled from device (sensor) code to view models ...

Your messages, in this model, active events that could acess your viewmodels as well as other structures.

A sample of this

In your view use :

```
public void MessegingCenterInit()
    {
        #region Bluetooth

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, string>("App", "Status_name", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            App.PVM.Name = $"{arg}";//using INotifyPropertyChanged and view model
            viewmodelMethod();//using only a viewmodel
         });
        #endregion
    }
```

in your model use:

```
  public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                App.PVM.Add_patient.AddCanExecuteChanged();//PVM is a viewmodel
                //The view model need to have INotifyPropertyChanged as a interface
           }
        }
```

In specific code you have (into a generic method or event):

```
string new_name = John;
MessagingCenter.Send<string,string>("App","Status_name",new_name);
```

There are several ways to do it, its a simple one, you can try use objects as sender with less information.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! That sounds really promising to me! Before I look into that further, I've got one more idea. Let's assume `MyModel` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and `MyViewModel` has a member of type `MyModel`, how could I register methods to react on model updates in `MyViewModel`?

Comment: Just wait a second, I'll insert in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin itself gives a really good example with their default Master-Detail Solution.

Just create a new Xamarin.Forms App and select the Master-Detail Layout. 
It includes several Views, ViewModels (with the BaseVIewModel) and some MockUp Data Classes.
For a start just have a look around there :)

Comment: I've seen those. The example has a simple POCO called `Item` under the models. But imho that's just nothing close to a model. Where do I store my actual data? Where would you put a central collection of POCOs? In the ViewModel? If so: How could you access the same data from different Views?

Comment: If it's just a view similar Views that need the Collection you can pass and use  the same ViewModel for several Screens (eg a Page displaying detail of an Item and one that edits that Item). That's especially handy cause changes to the View Models data are reflected trough the other views. If you really need it everywhere, make it static in your data and  asign that static collection to your VIewModel

Comment: Yeah, so the ViewModel is the actual Model. I think the name MVVM is completely misleading! It should be called VVM, because the Model is basically nothing else than a POCOs that does nothing.

Comment: I'd describe it as the model for what your data actually is. That's why its called model and not directly data. Most of the time data comes from outside input or a database, and the model describes what kind of data you're receiving and the methods for it, the view model handles it and the view displays it. But everyone has their own interpretation I guess

Comment: Yeah I'm with you on the fact that data comes from outside. But imho it's a Model's job to encapsulate exactly that! Stuff like data storage and handling, collections, atomic operations, data presentation, databases. I guess the difference in thinking/designing is where you actually keep the collection of objects, in the ViewModel or in the Model.

Answer (score -1):

In almost all cases there is no communication between the Model and ViewModel, and very rarely there is communication between the Model and View. If you need to communicate between Model and ViewModel it is extremely likely that you are doing something wrong.

To explain, your model usually describes some entity, like that you have the class Cat:

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

It is generally used in ViewModel either as the field or as a Collection like:

```
public class CatsViewModel
{
   public List<Cat> Cats {get; set;}
}
```

The cat shouldn't be able to update by itself, if it is updated it is done either by bindings with the view or somewhere from ViewModel.

So you have some architectural problems in your app, I think.

Comment: I find it rather weird to consider a `Cat` a model. It's just a simple class/object, a POCO. To me, a model is at least a collection of `Cat`s.

Comment: In Xamarin it is like that.

Comment: Ok, let's assume you want to keep a collection of `Cat` objects in your application that shall be accessible from different Views. The collection of cats shall be the same throughout the whole app. Where do you put that collection of `Cat`s?

Comment: Personally I use static class, but different developers will answer differently I guess.

Comment: See, I would create an actual `CatModel` which encapsulates all the `Cat` data in a `List<Cat>` and instantiate that Model once somewhere central in the App.